# How to change color of dot of radiobutton in silverlight?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

i want to change the color of dot showed on radio button selection. I don't found the proper solution for it. Is it possible or not? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes it is possible](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/72653/173860.aspx) by making a copy of the style and template (Blend is very helpful with this)

Then edit the template and modify the color.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use blend, it makes styling way easier. Just rightclick on the checkbox in Blend and then goto edit template -> edit current. From there you go to the States Manager for that checkbox and you can edit all the visual states for the check box. You want to edit the Checked Visual State.